# Mimicking the spacing of `\shortintertext`

Tags: spacing, displaystyle, mathematics

I am trying to have two `align*`-environments with some text between them. As the text is very short, I'd usually use `\shortintertext`. But I don't want the two environments to share the tab stops -- therefore, I have two distinct environments. But now, the spacing around the short line is too generous; how can I correct this?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\hrulefill
\begin{align}
    e &= q\\
    e &= q
\end{align}
\vskip-\belowdisplayskip
\vskip3pt
\hrulefill
\vskip3pt
\vskip-\abovedisplayskip
\begin{align}
    e &= q\\
        e &= q
\end{align}
\hrulefill
\begin{align}
    e &= q\\
    e &= q\\
    \shortintertext{\hrulefill}
    e &= q\\
    e &= q
\end{align}
\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't want the equations aligned, you might consider a single `gather*` with `\shortintertext`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The lines within each `align` are supposed to be aligned. I have updated the MWE. If I didn't need equation numbers, would a `gather*` with several `alinged`s inside be feasible?

Comment: `aligned` is intended to be able to be nested within *any* math environment.  (Even `$...$` in text.)  On the other hand, if every equation should be numbered, then `aligned` would allow only one number for that group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `align` inside `gather`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill
\begin{gather}
\begin{align}
    e &= qqqqqqq\\
    e &= qqqq
\end{align}
\shortintertext{something that occupies some space without any
real meaning, I like self-reference}
\begin{align}
    e &= qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq\\
    e &= qqqq
\end{align}
\shortintertext{something that occupies some space without any
real meaning, I like self-reference}
\begin{align}
    e &= qqqqqqqqq\\
    e &= q\\
\shortintertext{something that occupies some space without any
real meaning, I like self-reference}
    e &= qqqqq\\
    e &= q
\end{align}
\end{gather}
\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it intended to put `align` inside other math environments? If so, what is the difference between `aligned` and `align*`, if used in math mode?

Comment: @Bubaya Yes, the manual of `amsmath` explicitly specifies that `align` can be nested in `gather`. The difference is in the numbering of equations.